# Silent Refresh - Refreshing Access Tokens when using the Implicit Flow is not working on custom login URL

Tags: identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I'm using IdentityServer4(.NET Core API) and 'oidc-client' in Angular, In which I'm using custom login and logout urls, not default identityserver4 urls, So in this scenario silent-refresh request from 'oidc-client'. it returns 302, Still token is getting expired after sometimes automatically

IdentityServer4:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(opt =>
{
                opt.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/User/Login";
                opt.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/User/Logout";
                opt.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                opt.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                opt.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                opt.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
})
```

oidc-client:

```
getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
        return {
            authority: localStorage.getItem('authorizationRoot'),
            client_id: 'MileTMSAngapp',
            redirect_uri: localStorage.getItem('redirectUri'),
            post_logout_redirect_uri: 
            localStorage.getItem('postLogoutRedirectUri'),
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            scope: 'openid profile MileTMS',
            filterProtocolClaims: false,
            loadUserInfo: true,
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            silent_redirect_uri: localStorage.getItem('silentRedirectUri')
        };
    }
```

'Silent-Callback':

```
 return this.manager.signinSilentCallback()
        .then(doSomething => 'done');
```

Answer (score 0):

what kind of error are you seeing in the console?

With the minimal information that you have provided, my guess is that you are facing this issue. Hopefully, this helps.

[IdentityServer Session cookie is not sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292975/identityserver-session-cookie-is-not-sliding/53502650#53502650)

Comment: There is no error in console and i can see silent request in network also, Inspite of all these, token get expired before specified time

Comment: If I'm not wrong, token will not expire, check the session Cookie (IDSRV) validity time. Did you also check token validity using jwt.io ?